# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded log

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

While plotting multiple markers on a Google map, I got an **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** error message in the log for Ionic framework.

I am using a Cordova Google plugin for the map. Can anyone figure out where the error is in my code?

```
var autocompleteFrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputFrom, options);
var autocompleteto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputto,options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteFrom, 'place_changed', function() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var place = autocompleteFrom.getPlace();
    $rootScope.fromLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    $rootScope.fromLng = place.geometry.location.lng();
    $rootScope.from = place.formatted_address;
    $scope.placesfrom = $rootScope.from;
    fromlat = $rootScope.fromLat;
    fromlng = $rootScope.fromLng;
    var Mapoptions ={
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        zoomControl:false,
        draggable:true,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        scaleControl:false,
        streetViewControl:false,
        overviewMapControl:false,
        rotateControl:true
    }
    var googlemaphome = document.getElementById('googlemap-home');
    var Map = new google.maps.Map(googlemaphome,Mapoptions);
    var marker;
    var markers = [
            [fromlat,fromlng],
            [28.6328,77.2197]
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            icon: 'img/marker.png',
            map: Map
        });
    }
    Map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((Map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

> var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);

Since the subarrays in your `markers[]` array only have 2 elements, and the index for arrays starts at 0, I believe you should change this line to

> var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][***0***], markers[i][***1***]); //use 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2